# How there are so many dialects of English in England?

Tags: dialects, accent, british-english

I was just wondering how there are so many variations of dialects in England, which isn't really a very large country, they have Brummie, Yorkie, Cockney, the one in Liverpool, I don't know what's the name for that and etc. etc. So how did these counties acquire their distinct accents? I'm looking for definitive answer and if possible with some compelling historical evidence.

Comment: Yes, that's all right, I'm not surprised there are 100s of dialects still extant, but my question is how it was possible for these to have emerged in such a small country. My question primarily relates to England.

Comment: Norway has a far smaller population than England, but [even tiny communities have, or had, their own dialects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norwegian_dialects). This goes right down to the level of individual hamlets, or even farms! Obviously isolation was a factor in this, but it's worth pointing out that a small country can still develop very many dialects. England is not unique in this regard.

Comment: You have missed out many. There are the Geordie's (North East England), Scots, Welsh, Lancashire, the West Country, Norfolk & East Anglia, etc. the Liverpool accent, incidentally is known as Scouse. It is very different to the rest of Lancashire.

Comment: Indeed I missed out on countless more, but my question didn't relate to the number of dialects, but their origin and emergence.

Comment: @Silverfish Are you putting the differences down to isolation then?

Comment: The remarkable thing is that Britain has retained its regional accents in an age of great mobility and communication. When the BBC was founded in the 1920s some people predicted that it would spell the end of local accents in Britain. But today they are alive and well, perhaps to a greater extent than in any of the larger European countries.

Comment: If you want to hear a Scouse (Liverpool) accent, who better to listen to than the captain of the Liverpool football team (also former captain of England) Steven Gerrard. Try this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ifsu3SIC6kw

Comment: @WS2 I think as opposed to spelling an end to the various dialects, the modern age of vast communication has somewhat fostered their position. We see in advertisements people of assorted dialects given a chance to present their ideas and such. I think this way, all the dialects are brought together and embraced instead of transformed to one officially recognised and accepted one. It has worked like that in England but I'm not sure about other countries. French seem to have a very stable accent all throughout the country so they didn't have to confront this issue.

Comment: @WS2 Liverpool and English actor Stephen Graham isn't that bad for a Skouse accent either. :)

Comment: @AndySemyonov There are certainly strong regional accents in France, particularly in the South. You can tell Provencal people easily. The Marseilles accent is quite different to the Parisian, and Lyon is different again. And the French spoken in Belgium and Switzerland are each very distinct too, as is that of the north of France, around Lille. But when you consider that before the French Revolution at least half of what is now geographically France spoke a language other than French, it is remarkable that French today is as standardised as it is.

Comment: I've often wondered about this same thing. My theory is that most British natives not moving around a lot could be the reason to this. Indeed, when I'd been there, I learned that several countrymen didn't travel out of their village since many generations!

Comment: @WS2 Oh I wasn't aware of the variations in French, so thanks for pointing that out. Well then I think that only leaves Russian and German with not having too many subtleties compared to English.

Comment: @AndySemyonov I don't know much about either Russian or German, but you can rest assured there will be important regional variations. Though a young friend of ours who graduated in Russian and now lives in Moscow did say, that quite remarkably in Russia, such a large country, that its regional accents were not as marked as those in Britain.

Comment: @PrahladYeri I think you will find that that is a considerable exaggeration!

Comment: In terms of population, the UK would appear to be one of the _largest_ European countries (Wikipedia says some 64 million.)

Comment: @anemone - The number of dialects is not so much a questions of the number of inhabitants, but more a question of history and internal as well as external dynamics that inflenced the original local languages.

Comment: @Josh61 True, beyond doubt. I'm just commenting on the OP's remark that UK is not such a large country; I doubt it is a defensible claim. Moreover, perhaps you will agree, it is not really relevant to the post.

Comment: @WS2 Historically, the more movement happens within in a region, and more dialog takes place, their dialect ultimately *balances* itself and the same language is spoken in the entire region. For instance, the American states of Texas, California, Louisiana, etc. are each roughly the size of England. Yet, only one kind of English is spoken in each of these states. California English might differ from Louisiana, but within California, there is a standard.

Comment: @PrahladYeri That's an a priori justification you're giving. It's a compelling argument that as people intermingle with each other their dialect is stabalised. But throughout history, of all the people, Europeans have been in contact with each other more than anyone I guess, yet the vernacular, the national languages of various nation-states have been preserved over centuries. The isolation theory you used to base your argument at first, would easily be be debunked by many.

Comment: Andy, what would the form of a sufficient or non-a priori argument be for you? All we have is historical evidence, we cant really experiment on populations to see what causes more language diversity.

Comment: @Mitch I haven't yet been apprised of any historical evidence that would justify the language subtleties in England. I know it's an uneasy question for most people, but I was wondering if someone would have a convincing theory to expound the origins of dialects of the said region. Some of the answers have been helpful, especially from WS2, but I'm still looking for a more definitive answer

Comment: Speech patterns, like fashion, are a way of fitting into a group. Children ape the social norms of their families, friends, neighbors, class (yes, there are still class systems in most English speaking countries) and grooves form. Obviously many modify and blend these patterns, but enough sticks to preserve regional dialects. In a city like New York, there are still distinct patterns even by neighborhood.

Comment: @AndySemyonov - In case you don't know it already, you might like  the following series by BBC:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VsVz5U76kX0

Comment: Andy, I think you have the hypothesis that English is more varied nowadays geographically than others. We should probably define lots first, but for canonical definitions, it's not the case (most European langs have lots of regional dialects; maybe not Russian?).  But let's suppose it _is_ the case. A possible explanation (is it the right form) would be that there is no strong central language authority or strong social adoption tendency. Are you looking for a reason why language X is more diverse than language Y? geographic and social barriers.

Comment: @Mitch That's a very nice claim you make about lack of strong central language authority, I find it compelling indeed. As far as I'm aware of medieval England, the RP was confined to exclusive spheres, mainly that of Courts and Churches. To proselytize this language doesn't appear to have been an ambition of many in those days. So yes, you do make a good case of it there. Someone told me yesterday, a language changes dialects after ever 12 miles lol I don't much stock in that claim.

Comment: 12 miles? That's surely dependent (in a very nonlinear way) on population density. What was the Pygmalion quote...["I can place any man within six miles. I can place him within two miles in London. Sometimes within two streets."](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/3825/3825-h/3825-h.htm)

Answer (score 2):

> - The dialects of present-day English can be seen as the continuation of the dialect areas which established themselves in the Old English period.

The following  [extract](https://www.uni-due.de/SHE/HE_DialectsModernEnglish.htm) can help:

HISTORICAL OUTLINE:

> - The dialectal division of the narrower region of England into:
> - 1) a northern, 2) a central and 3) a (subdivided) southern region has been retained to the present-day.
> - The linguistic study of the dialects of English goes back to the 19th century when, as an offspin of Indo-European studies, research into (rural) dialects of the major European languages was considerably developed. The first prominent figure in English dialectology is Alexander Ellis (mid-19th century), followed somewhat later by Joseph Wright (late 19th and early 20th century).
> - The former published a study of English dialects and the latter a still used grammar of English dialects at the beginning of the present century. It was not until the Survey of English Dialects, first under the auspices of Eugen Dieth and later of Harald Orton, that such intensive study of (rural) dialects was carried out (the results appeared in a series of publications in the 1950s and 1960s).

STANDARD FEATURES OF ENGLISH DIALECTS:

> - The main divide between north and south can be drawn by using the pronunciation of the word but. Either it has a /u/ sound (in the north) or the lowered and unrounded realisation typical of Received Pronunciation in the centre and south, /ʌ/. An additional isogloss is the use of a dark /ɫ/ in the south versus a clear /l/ in the north. The south can be divided by the use of syllable-final /r/ which is to be found in the south western dialects but not in those of the south east. The latter show ‘initial softening’ as in single, father, think with the voiced initial sounds /z-, v-, ð/ respectively.

( [www.uni-due.de](http://www.uni-due.de))

List of main English dialects in Europe:

> - **British English (BrE)**
> - North
> - Northern:
>
>   - Northeast (including Mackem (spoken in Sunderland) and Geordie)
>     Lower North
>   - Central North (including Cumbrian dialect)
>     Tyke (spoken in Yorkshire)
>     Central Lancashire
>     Humberside
> - Central
>
>   - West Central
>     Merseyside
>     Northwest Midlands
>     West Midlands (including Black Country English and Brummie)
>   - East Central
>     Central Midlands
>     Northeast Midlands
>     East Midlands
> - South
>
>   - East
>     South Midlands
>     East Anglia
>     Home Counties
>   - Southwest
>     Upper Southwest
>     Central Southwest
>     Lower Southwest
> - **Corby English**
> - **Scotland**
>
>   - Northern Scots
>   - Central Scots
>   - South Scots
>   - Insular Scots
>     Ulster Scots
> - **Wales**
>
>   - Welsh English
>   - North East English a toned down Scouse/Manchester accent due to English population
>   - Pembrokeshire dialect
> - **Ireland**
> - Republic of Ireland
>
>   - Hiberno-English
>   - Yola dialect
> - Northern Ireland
>
>   - Mid Ulster English
>   - Ulster Scots English
> - **Isle of Man**
>
>   - Manx English
> - **Channel Islands**
>
>   - Guernsey English
>   - Jersey English
> - **Gibraltar**
>
>   - Llanito

[Wikipedia](http://mural.uv.es/naregar/presentacion/wiki_article_list_of_dialects_of_the_english_language.html#Europe)

Answer (score 0):

Dialects are everywhere in any language, because the whole of a population is no homogeneous body but an agglomeration of various ethnic groups. Even if there were a homogeneous population varieties would come into being as language has a natural tendency to variety. But there is also the opposite tendency due to printed media to make language uniform. So most people master the standard language and a dialect.

Comment: Please no more a priori arguments.

Comment: I  know Kant's philosophical terms a priori and a posteriori knowledge, but I can't understand what you mean by "no more a priori arguments". By the way the largest regional diversification has been found in the German language area.